# wordpress REST API draft posts not showing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Using the Wordpress REST API I am trying to get draft posts only. However the API responds with only the published posts when I pass the query in both cases.

A: http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?status=draft

B: http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[post_status]=draft

How can I see only the draft posts? I am using the JWT Authentication for WP-API plugin for authentication but disabling this doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: There isn't enough clarification on this but I do know it has to do with authentication permissions.

Comment: That's the answer I get: {"code":"rest_invalid_param","message":"Invalid parameter(s): status","data":{"status":400,"params":{"status":"Status is forbidden."}}} I think it's just not supported.

Comment: Hi @Wazzaday !  Any news on the matter ?  Thank you...

Comment: The correct solution is status=draft. But you need to make sure you are authenticated with a user that can see draft posts, otherwise the status field is just ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This is because just installing the JWT Auth plugin doesn't solve the problem. There are also some modifications to be performed on the `.htaccess` file as well as in `wp-config.php`.

I hit a similar problem but with private posts, so I created a video detailing the steps you need to follow to install and configure the JWT Authentication plugin.

https://youtu.be/Mp7T7x1oxDk

Answer (score 0):

for getting draft posts  you should send an Authorization token, so you can use
JWT Authentication for WP-API plugin for getting it and use it anywhere,
and for getting posts with drafts status you should send 'status': 'draft' as a param in your request, also if you want to get all of status you should send  'status': 'any' in your params in request. :)